# Python/django import nightmare (unique case)

Tags: python, django, import, python-import

I have a project structure like this,

```
myAPI/  <---
      announcements/
            models.py
            views.py
            tests.py   <---
      tests/ <----
            models.py 
            views.py 
      myAPI/ <---
         settings.py 
         ....
```

Now I am not able to import my tests(django app) to my announcements app.

**announcements/models.py**

```
from tests.models import Test   <--- Error!!
```

because it is looking for a class in **django/announcements/tests.py file**

I also tried:

```
from myAPI.tests.models import Test   <--- Error!!
```

It looks for a module in myAPI folder(with settings.py file) which obviously throws an error.

Any help with this import would be appreciated! 
EDIT: Using python 2.7

Comment: I can suggest a quick way. change the file name.

Comment: well, that way the test runners would not be able to find my Test Cases files, I assume!

Comment: Then change the app name.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the problems with Python 2 that was fixed by Python 3.

If you put `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of your module, then all imports are absolute by default, and it will work (it's the Python 3 behaviour). Use `from . import <thing>` to import from the same directory as the current module.

That said, I dislike calling an app "tests", as many test runners will assume that there are tests to run in there.